# React - for loop inside return

Tags: reactjs

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z2x6je?file=index.js)

I'm trying to create a simple text fade function - I'm outputting the text from an array and I wanted to fade the text in and out in order so - 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', etc. I want this to continue in a loop.

I thought I might be able to do this with a for loop and loop through the elements adding and removing a fade class.

In my demo I'm just trying to get the loop working in the return but it won't

How do I use a for loop in React.

Or is there a better way to do this.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

  const colors = [
    'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Black'
  ]

  return (
    <div className='titles'>
      {colors.map((color, i) => (
        <p key={i} className={'title-'+i}>{color}</p>
      ))}
    </div>

    {this.loopFun()}

  );

  const loopFun = () => {
      for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
      console.log(colors[i])
    }
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- You need to define functions before the return statement
- You can't mix class and functional syntax (don't use this.)
- You need to wrap function in return within a div or other element

A working example could look like this:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {

  const colors = [
    'Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Black'
  ]

  const loopFun = () => {
      for(let i=0; i<colors.length; i++){
      console.log(colors[i])
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className='titles'>
      {colors.map((color, i) => (
        <p key={i} className={'title-'+i}>{color}</p>
      ))}    
      {loopFun()}
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can install eslint with react plugins / rules in your local IDE to get warnings / errors about this kind of issues.

Please check out the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html